# How do I know which revisions have been deployed in AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

In the revision screen of AppMaker, I can find which revision is currently deployed (the "deployment" column), but how can I know which other revisions have been deployed before ? So I can rollback to one of them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use tags. In theory, when you switch this view from `Minute` to `Day`, App Maker should show only revision that were tagged or deployed (if you use real deployment instead of Preview for development, then you'll have lots of such revisions and at this time there is no better way to find something there).
[image: AM tags]

Comment: ok so it's what I thought, there is no native way. We'll use tags in the future.